# psplot: square root of negative number

Tags: pstricks, postscript

Is there a possibility to have `psplot` automatically *ignore* an invalid range?

Example:

```
x 2 sub sqrt
```

This cann't be plotted requesting `\psplot{0}{10}`, but only when using `\psplot{2}{10}`.

Of course my formula is more complicated than this and there can be the case that there are several intervals where there can be `(negative number) sqrt`.

On top of that I'm using `\multido`, so it would be really annoying if I would have to find every point where there would be the case of `-1 sqrt`...

What I would like, how it should behave in my opinion: It should only plot the real value of the function and skip the imaginary ones.

edit: MWE (not working because of the negative square root):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=1cm}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido,pst-func}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,6)

\psaxes[labels=none]{->}(0,0)(10,6)
\multido{\n=1.1+.1}{20}{%
\psplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=.5mm]{0}{9}{5 2 3.1416 mul div \n\space 2 exp x 10 mul sin 2 exp mul 1 sub sqrt mul}
}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you posted a MWE which shows how you're encountering this, it'd be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Added MWE. I thought that this would not be needed, because my question is more general and not just on the solution of my specific problem.

Comment: If you have not seen my update, this comment is given to notify you.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @DL6ER: there is also a `Sqrt` instead of `sqrt`. It gives 0 back for negative values, see my example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pstVerb{/mySQRT { dup 0 lt { 0 }{ sqrt } ifelse } bind def }%

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,6)
    \psaxes[labels=none]{->}(0,0)(10,6)
    \multido{\n=1.1+.3}{20}{%
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{9}{5 2 Pi mul div \n\space 2 exp x 10 mul sin 2 exp mul 1 sub mySQRT mul}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit:

I just got the following revelation.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pstVerb{/mySQRT { dup 0 lt { neg sqrt neg }{ sqrt } ifelse } bind def }%
\psset{plotpoints=200}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,6)
    \psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none,linewidth=0](9,6)}
        \multido{\n=1.1+.3}{20}{%
        \psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{9}{5 2 Pi mul div \n\space 2 exp x 10 mul sin 2 exp mul 1 sub mySQRT mul}}
    \endpsclip
    \psaxes[labels=none]{->}(0,0)(10,6)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `mySQRT` can also be invoked in `algebraic` form as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pstVerb{/mySQRT { dup 0 lt { neg sqrt neg }{ sqrt } ifelse } bind def }%
\psset{plotpoints=200,algebraic}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,6)
    \psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none,linewidth=0](9,6)}
        \multido{\n=1.1+.3}{20}{%
        \psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{9}{5*mySQRT((\n*sin(10*x/180*Pi))^2-1)/(2*Pi)}}
    \endpsclip
    \psaxes[labels=none]{->}(0,0)(10,6)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

But don't forget to convert degree to radian.

Comment: This doesn't look nice...if there is no other solution I will go for `gnuplot`.

Comment: @DL6ER: Herbert might be able to hack `psplot` to skip plotting the negative parts. I cannot do it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{border=1cm}
\usepackage{pst-plot,multido}

\begin{document}
\psset{yunit=2}
\begin{pspicture}(10,3)
\psaxes[labels=none]{->}(0,0)(10,3)
  \multido{\n=1.1+.1}{20}{%
  \psplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=.5mm,plotpoints=500]{0}{9}{5 2 3.1416 mul div \n\space 2 exp x 10 mul sin 2 exp mul 1 sub 
  dup 0 lt % negative value??
    { pop pop 0 /L /moveto load def } % if yes then use moveto
    { sqrt mul /L /lineto load def }  % if not then go on
  ifelse }%
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: It will be nicer if you can also make it possible in `algebraic`. :-)

Comment: This also looks nice

Comment: `multido` is automatically loaded by `pst-plot`.