# Good way to cut off extra range data in listplot

Tags: pstricks

Using `listplot`, is there a way to cut off extra range data?

The option `yEnd=10` simply removes the points above `y=10` so that it changes the overall shape of the curve.

Here is example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\def\data{0 0 1 4 1.5 1.75 2.25 4 2.75 7 3 9 3.5 13 4 15 4.5 15 5 1 5.5 1}
\begin{psgraph}(0,0)(6,10){10cm}{3cm}
\listplot[showpoints=true]{\data}
\end{psgraph}

\vspace*{20mm}

\begin{psgraph}(0,0)(6,10){10cm}{3cm}
\listplot[showpoints=true,yEnd=10]{\data}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

Comment: General comment: For vertical spacing, use `ex` instead of `mm` (and use `em` for horizontal spacing). The former is font dependent.

Comment: OK, thank you. Does somebody know how to make the result of the quoted code appear? (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120010/psplot-square-root-of-negative-number) for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\def\data{0 0 1 4 1.5 1.75 2.25 4 2.75 7 3 9 3.5 13 4 15 4.5 15 5 1 5.5 1}
\begin{psgraph}[Dy=2](0,0)(6,10){10cm}{3cm}
\listplot[showpoints]{\data}
\end{psgraph}

\vspace*{20mm}    
\begin{psgraph}[Dy=2](0,0)(6,10){10cm}{3cm}
\psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none](-5pt,-5pt)(6,10)}
  \listplot[showpoints]{\data}
\endpsclip
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why doesn't this code compile on LuaLaTeX but compiles well on XeLaTeX without any extra packages ?. What does XeLaTeX has which LuaLaTeX misses to compile a PSTricks code ?

Comment: Frequently done errors No4 at http://PSTricks.tug.org

Comment: Why cannot we have LuaLaTeX use the dvi -->pdf route like XeLaTeX to help PSTricks users and wont hurt any other users I suppose

Comment: `lualatex --output-format=dvi ... `

Comment: I mean direct path without an intermediate file/step like xelatex which uses `xdvipdfmx` i suppose

Comment: My ignorant thoughts was to get `extended DVI (.xdv)` format from `lualatex` and give (.xdv) to `xdvipdfmx` which can understand PS specials well to get `.pdf` directly similar to xelatex.

Comment: Thank you Herbert, and sorry for my late answer (connection problems)